# Secure a wifi connecction, boot to iceweasal and auto login to OWA

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi2, outlook-web-app, iceweasel

The Project: A Raspberry Pi showing a shared calendar in OWA, basically this: http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Wall-Mounted-Google-Calendar/ for an outlook Calendar instead of a Google one.

I have a grand total of 24 hours of Linux experience so far, This is where i am at:

Pi has Raspbian running

Iceweasel installed and running (Have to use Iceweasel as it is the only Raspbian web client that will show the full version of OWA, all others are locked to light version which doesn't show full week at a time and doesn't show shared calendars)

Iceweasel configured to start on XWindows start

Iceweasel configured to run fullscreen with no menus

Managed to get the Wifi working (This was a drama and a half but hey, I learned a little bit more about wifi configurations so all good)

Can log into OWA and get it to show exactly what I want (Shared calendar) but this is done using a keyboard.

What I need help with:

```
1)
```

Can I get the Wifi to secure a connection before XWindows fires? Currently it tells me it is trying to get a connection a few times when booting then fails. I then run the wifi gui in XWindows and click connect and it seems to connect without getting an IP address. Then I go to a terminal and type `sudo dhclient -r eth0` followed by `sudo dhclient eth0` and I can now see an IP in the wifi gui.

Now when I open Iceweasel I have a connection and can login.

```
2)
```

This is probably more of an OWA question than a linux one, can you get OWA to auto login with some supplied credentials and can you get it to auto show a shared calendar rather than me having to click "Calendar" then tick the shared calendar and untick the default one?

So far I have tried just about everything I have found on google (Which is how I got as far as I have) but I am unsure what to even search for with regards to my wifi issue as I don't know what the correct term would be for it.

If this is not possible then fine I can work something else out but I don't want to keep trawling the net for an answer that might not exist.

Comment: An update, Issue 1 appeared to be a dead wifi dongle dropping in and out, replaced that and it all works as expected. Still need help with part 2 if anyone knows the answer.

Comment: Update 2, it looks like the exchange server needs to be configured for passwordless login on OWA: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998638.aspx